# Is $f =g$ when $g=\limsup f_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

f and g are two functions . Is $f =g$ $\mu$ a.e when $g=\limsup f_n$ when n -> infinity ?

we have $f_n$ --> f $\mu$ a.e , $f_n$ is measurable for all n in N.

I think they will equal because when f_n - > f , g = limsup f  = f at each x that makes f_n --> f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes these are the same. The pointwise limit is the same as the pointwise limsup everywhere where the limit exists.